# Hi, I want to hide one particular <li> element among others, which is under an <ul> element. But hide() has hidden all the <li> elements

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var privileges=$("#privText").val();
 var privilegeArray=privileges.split(",");
 var liArray=$(".dyn").find("li");
 
  $.each(liArray,function(i,val){
   alert("tesT:"+$(this).text());
   liText=$(this).text().trim();
   var lid=$(this).attr("id");
   alert("l: "+lid);
                 $.each(privilegeArray,function(index,value){

   if(value.trim()!=lid){
    alert("privilege not matched:"+value);
                                $("#"+lid).hide();
   }else{
    
    alert("matched in else");
    alert("privilege value: "+value);
   }   
  });
  
 });
});
```

This is the HTML. I am trying to find the li's id under the ul and match them with the privileges. If it does not match, it will hide the li, selected using the Id attribute, otherwise it will be left as it is. I have checked the if logic, its working fine, then also its hiding all the li elements.

```html
<ul>
  <li id="mainLi">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Administration</a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level dyn">
                      <li id="Admission_admin">
                           <a href="#">Admission_admin</a>
                      </li>
                      <li id="Office_admin">
                           <a href="#">Office_admin</a>
                      </li>
          <li id="Account_admin">
                           <a href="#">Account_admin</a>
                      </li>
                </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<input type="text" value="Account_admin,Transport_manage,Transport_view,Transport_delete"id="privText"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d8nn2ewk/1/)

```
  var privileges=$("#privText").val();
    var privilegeArray=privileges.split(",");
    var liArray=$(".dyn").find("li");

        $.each(liArray,function(i,val){
            //alert("tesT:"+$(this).text());
            liText=$(this).text().trim();
            var lid=$(this).attr("id");
            //alert("l: "+lid);

            var idx = $.inArray(lid, privilegeArray);

            if(idx == -1){
                //alert("privilege not matched:"+value);
                                $("#"+lid).hide();
            }else{
                 $("#"+lid).show();
                //alert("matched in else");
                //alert("privilege value: "+value);
            }

    });
```

Comment: Incase you have time. As for knowledge, may I know why my script was not working?@SimarjeetSingh Panghlia

Comment: because when u r gettiing rhe account_admin value from first loop and again u r comparing the this value with the loop of privilage array at first time u r gettimg the same value but second time in second loop u r comparing Account_admin with Transport_manage which is not correct